# Sliding expiration JWT in order to prevent logout to the user

Tags: .net, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc, rest

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project that requests are being authenticated by cookie with sliding expiration true.

Now according to the requirements this MVC project is going to be written with as .NET Core project and requests should be authenticated with JWT.

What is the best way to implement sliding expiration for JWT?

One idea I read is to check the JWT and if needed reissuing a new one and send it via a response header so the client can get the new JWT and update the existing token.

I wonder where the best place is to authenticate the JWT and reissuing a new one if needed according to some configuration and send it in a response header (reissuing JWT will be only for existing valid token)

- AuthorizationFilter
- CustomAuthentication middleware

or any other place?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` class. You may be able to override one of its protected virtual methods, `ValidateLifetime()`, to do what you want. This way, you may not even need to re-issue the JWT--just specify that it's still valid based on your window calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I wander if in this way still need to update the token with new expiration time no? so next time the expiration will be the sliding expiration value

Comment: Yes. That was my point. You wouldn't need to re-issue a new token if you could just determine whether the presented token is still valid. The important bit will be to determine the date/time of the last request (using that JWT) in order to keep sliding the window forward.